# How do I fix the CSS to align my text while using my currency switching plugin?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a pricing page as seen [here](https://tmkings.com/pricing/), and while using a currency switching Wordpress plugin, it has thrown my text out of alignment. I can't seem to figure out what CSS needs to change in order to bring it back into alignment. Specifically, the $250 needs to be brought down onto the same line as the other text. Any suggestions are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and [mre]. "I can't seem to figure out what CSS needs to change in order to bring it back into alignment." We can only possibly propose changes to CSS that is actually shown to us. We can also only possibly know what parts of the CSS impact on what parts of the text in your HTML, if we see relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

While this answer doesn't meet the required standards, I understand the need for a solution. Just fix the position using relative positioning.

```
.cs-converter-wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! May I ask how you knew it was off by 4px and 1px from top and left? My inspection tool was not showing any added margin or padding.

Comment: Yeah something was weird there. I just moved it a little by the eye. `position:relative` is useful and ain't no shame using it.